# C# MVC API debugging, trigger breakpoints with Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, debugging

I have a C# MVC web API that I publish to a local IIS instance for testing with Postman as it requires authentication headers, `POST` requests etc I cannot call directly from a browser (without building a front-end).

I am trying to debug the API, by adding breakpoints and attaching Visual Studio 2017 to the `w3wp.exe` process for the API. However when I call the API from Postman the breakpoints do not get triggered and postman gets an API response.

Looking for recommendations on how to trigger breakpoints and debug an MVC API when using a tool like Postman to make the API calls.

Comment: The entire ASP.NET MVC infrastructure is highly unit testable.  Are you sure you need Postman?  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486658

Answer (score 0):

You pointed out that you published it to IIS. When publishing, you might have chosen the release option which gets rid of all the debugging options and environments making the code more efficient and faster.

I suggest that you republish your project by checking the Debug option rather than the release option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using a local folder publish with the debug profile, through a browser I can hit breakpoints pre-auth, but I can't hit them with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your service is compiled in debug mode before it is deployed to local IIS. You can check if you see .pdb files along with dll files in the debug folder.